# Boost ASIO ip tcp iostream expires_from_now doesn't result in an error when connection fails

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

We've come across a strange situation where our code reports that it has successfully opened a connection to an unreachable address.  But it only happens when we actively reduce the time-out for a `boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream`:

```
void Connect(std::string address, std::string port) {
    std::cout << "Waiting to connect: " << address << " at port " << port << "\n";
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream s;

    s.expires_from_now(std::chrono::seconds(5));
    s.connect(address, port);

    if (!s) {
        std::cout << "Unable to connect: " << s.error().message() << "\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Success!" << "\n";
    }              
}
```

With the above code, `connect("192.168.25.25", "1234");` will quickly report "Success!", even though the address is unreachable.  If we remove the `expires_from_now`, then we instead get "Unable to connect: Connection timed out" after about 2 minutes - as we expect.

I would have expected that changing the timeout using `expires_from_now` would result in a time-out error state.  We're using boost 1.68.

Is there any other way to find out that the time-out is reached, or perhaps more appropriately, whether the connection has been established?

Comment: Just want to see what `s.error().message()` returns

Comment: @Explorer_N - it returns "Success" when it times-out.

Comment: People who downvoted: even if the source of the question was confusion, the question can be valuable. In fact, more so, as many others often have similar confusions

Comment: I've updated the question.  The confusion perhaps comes from the fact that all other situations are actually failures, while the time-out isn't necessarily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Success" indication just means that nothing has gone wrong yet. It does *not* mean that the `connect` has succeeded. You chose not to wait to find out whether the connect succeeded or failed and to instead time out the wait for that result.

You cannot make a TCP connect operation fail early. The rules for the conditions under which a TCP connect attempt fails are part of the TCP specification and just setting a timeout won't change how long it takes the connection attempt to fail.

Querying for the remote_endpoint will however indicate an error condition if the connection has not been established, for example:

```
boost::system::error_code ec;
s.socket().remote_endpoint(ec);
if (ec)
{
    std::cout << "Unable to connect\n";
}
```

Comment: That doesn't quite answer the question - despite being informative.  All other aspects of the iostream will raise exceptions if the operation times out - but this gives no indication that it has returned early.

Comment: @Arunas There isn't really any actual question. The closest thing to a question seems to be asking why your code "reports that it has successfully opened a connection" and I'm saying that it hasn't reported that. The connection attempt is still in progress and has neither succeeded nor failed. The code only initiates a connection attempt and checks if it failed.

Comment: well, the last sentence is actually a question. "Is there any other way to find out that the time-out is reached?"

Comment: Oh, sorry. The short answer is no, but that's almost certainly the wrong question to ask. What you probably really want to know is whether the socket is now successfully connected or not, which you can tell by requesting the peer address.

Comment: Ok, I'd argue that it's a similar result for either question, but fair enough.  Do you want to finish the answer?

Comment: @Arunas While the results are similar, they are different questions. And it's the other one that you *really* want the answer to. The answer is really that you're asking the wrong question. You don't care about the timeout, you care about the state of the connection.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of completing the answer -